# Missing chunk of data when sending file over

Tags: python

I'm having issues trying to send a file over in an internal server. I've pasted my code here:

```
# sends the adb file chunk by chunk (blocks of bytes)
chunk = file.read(4096)
while (chunk):
    c.send(chunk)
    chunk = file.read(4096)
```

It doesn't send all the data, it always sends roughly the first 68ish% (or above) of the data and misses the end part of the data. I was wondering what the issue is and how to solve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into what the 4096 part means?

Comment: @Jarad it's the amount of bytes in the chunk. So how much is being sent each time to the server.